# Can't override Bootstrap class?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to increase the font size of the on a site and I can't seem to override the default CSS. Below is a screen shot of the CSS that is applied when looking at it with the Developer Tools. I'm trying to increase the size to 14px. I've tried a couple different CSS styles without any luck. I've also cleared the browser cache each time I've tested it.

In my LESS file I have the following:

```
@font-size-base:    14px;
```

I've tried adding the following in my LESS file as well:

```
div.container.body-container{
  font-size: @font-size-base !important;
}

AND

.container.body-container{
  font-size: @font-size-base !important;
}

AND

.body-container{
  font-size: @font-size-base !important;
}
```

You can see something is overwriting the font to make it 11px.

[image]

[image]

***** UPDATE *****

Here is the entry from the bundle. The site.css comes after Bootstrap.css file.

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                      "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                      "~/Scripts/ui/jquery-ui.css",
                      "~/Content/site.css"));
```

Comment: Have you checked if the element has inline css?

Comment: @MarcAlexander...this was basically it in a way.

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

When you include your CSS/LESS file in the HTML make sure it comes after the Bootstrap CSS/LESS.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put your css file over the another one in your index.html file.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, check the order of your CSS calls. But also, in your screenshot, the font size is being inherited `.body-content`, not `.body-container`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the suggestions. I'm taking over a project and the developer before me didn't use a style sheet at all, everything is inline styles. Based on the suggestion above I found the inline style which I would have never thought to look at. They had put the inline style directly in the container on the _Layout.cshtml page. I removed the inline style and it worked.

```
<div class="container body-content" style="font-size:11px">
     @RenderBody()
</div>
```